# Find the average overall

Tags: average

We have a debtor table with a field average days to pay. that is, the average number of days the debtor takes to pay an invoice.

If I want to know whether the average days to pay overall is increasing or decreasing how would I calculate that?

At first I thought it was simply sum(AverageDaysToPay) / NumberOfDebtors but this seems wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Increasing with respect to time?  You can use a moving average and see if the moving average is increasing.

Comment: yeah I see what you're saying but I wanted to calculate the overall average across all the debtors using the existing average days to pay for each debtor.  I thought I could do this by simply summing all of the averages and then dividing by the number of debtors.